Change Tracking Using Databricks Autoloader and ForEachBatch
I am using Autoloader in Trigger Once mode to load Parquet files from an S3 location. My goal is to implement change data capture by comparing the source and target Delta tables to identify and capture INSERTS, UPDATES, and DELETES. Instead of performing a MERGE, I aim to build an append-only table that logs these changes. Below is my ForEachBatch upsert function. Although it runs, it does not capture any DELETES or UPDATES.
# Inputs

# Batch #1

batch_1_timestamp = "2024-07-19"
data = [
("1", "John", batch_1_timestamp),
("2", "David", batch_1_timestamp),
]

# Batch #2

batch_2_timestamp = "2024-07-20"
data = [
("1", "John", batch_2_timestamp), # Same record
("2", "David Jones", batch_2_timestamp), # Updated record
("3", "Bob", batch_2_timestamp),   # New record
]

# Batch #3

batch_3_timestamp = "2024-07-21"
data = [
("2", "David", batch_3_timestamp), # Update
("3", "Bob", batch_3_timestamp), # Same
# 1 deleted
]

# Expected Output

| id | name | batch_timestamp | operation_type
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1 | John   | 2024-07-19 | INSERT |
| 2  | David   | 2024-07-19 | INSERT |
| 2  | David  Jones | 2024-07-20 | UPDATE |
| 3  | Bob | 2024-07-20 | INSERT |
| 2 | David | 2024-07-21 | UPDATE |
| 1  | John | 2024-07-21 | DELETE |

def upsertToDelta(batch_df: DataFrame, batch_id: int):
    target_table = (
        spark
        .table(target_table_qualified)
        )

    hashed_df = batch_df
    df_source = utl.add_row_hash_to_dataframe(
        df=hashed_df,
        ignore_columns=metadata_columns
    )
    
    created_at_timestamp = datetime.now()

    new_records = df_source.alias("s").join(
        target_table.alias("t"),
        on=[
            col("s.id") == col("t.id")
        ],
        how = "left"
    ).filter(
        col("t.id").isNull()
    ).select(
        "s.*",
        lit("INSERT").alias("operation_type"),
        lit(created_at_timestamp).alias("created_at"),
    )
    
    updated_records = df_source.alias("s").join(
        target_table.alias("t"),
        on=[
            col("s.id") == col("t.id"),
            col("s.batch_timestamp") > col("t.batch_timestamp")
        ],
        how="inner"
    ).filter(
        col("s.row_hash") != col("t.row_hash")
    ).select(
        "s.*",
        lit("UPDATE").alias("operation_type"),
        lit(created_at_timestamp).alias("created_at")
    )
    
    deleted_records = (
        target_table.alias("t")
        .join(
        df_source.alias("s"),
        on=[
            col("t.id") == col("s.id"),
        ],
        how="left_anti"
    )
        .select('t.*')
        .withColumn("operation_type", lit("DELETE"))
        .withColumn("created_at", lit(created_at_timestamp))
    )

    df_processed = new_records.union(updated_records).union(deleted_records)

    df_processed.write.saveAsTable(
        target_table_qualified,
        format="delta",
        mode="append",
    )
    

# Write file stream
write_stream = (df_converted.writeStream
                .format("delta")
                .outputMode("append")
                .option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode", "rescue")
                .foreachBatch(upsertToDelta)
                .queryName(f"BronzeMerge[{target_table_qualified}]")
                .trigger(once=True)
                .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_location)
                .start())
write_stream.awaitTermination()


You code works fine all you have to do is hashing only the data columns.
In your case only id and name is the data columns and hash them only.
Here is the code for hashing.
metadata_columns = ["id","name"]
df_source = batch_df.withColumn("row_hash", md5(concat_ws("||", *[col(c) for c in batch_df.columns if c in metadata_columns ])))

Full code.
def upsertToDelta(batch_df, batch_id):
    target_table = (
        spark
        .table("target_table")
        )
    hashed_df = batch_df
    df_source = batch_df.withColumn("row_hash", md5(concat_ws("||", *[col(c) for c in batch_df.columns if c in ["id","name"]])))
    
    created_at_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()

    new_records = df_source.alias("s").join(
        target_table.alias("t"),
        on=[
            col("s.id") == col("t.id")
        ],
        how = "left"
    ).filter(
        col("t.id").isNull()
    ).select(
        "s.*",
        lit("INSERT").alias("operation_type"),
        lit(created_at_timestamp).alias("created_at"),
    )
    
    updated_records = df_source.alias("s").join(
        target_table.alias("t"),
        on=[
            col("s.id") == col("t.id"),
            col("s.batch_timestamp") > col("t.batch_timestamp")
        ],
        how="inner"
    ).filter(
        col("s.row_hash") != col("t.row_hash")
    ).select(
        "s.*",
        lit("UPDATE").alias("operation_type"),
        lit(created_at_timestamp).alias("created_at")
    )
    
    deleted_records = (
        target_table.alias("t")
        .join(
        df_source.alias("s"),
        on=[
            col("t.id") == col("s.id"),
        ],
        how="left_anti"
    )
        .select('t.*')
        .withColumn("operation_type", lit("DELETE"))
        .withColumn("created_at", lit(created_at_timestamp))
    )

    df_processed = new_records.union(updated_records).union(deleted_records)

    df_processed.write.saveAsTable(
        "target_table",
        format="delta",
        mode="append",
    )

Output:



id
name
batch_timestamp
row_hash
operation_type
created_at




1
John
2024-07-19
291e4554cceec860944748c36166eeab
DELETE
2024-07-24T05:55:52.383+00:00


2
David
2024-07-19
8a92a032edf462cfec7045f59d481172
INSERT
2024-07-24T05:54:19.069+00:00


1
John
2024-07-19
291e4554cceec860944748c36166eeab
INSERT
2024-07-24T05:54:19.069+00:00


2
David Jones
2024-07-20
dfb940cf7f6a4feee6091029406c6ff2
UPDATE
2024-07-24T05:55:41.553+00:00


3
Bob
2024-07-20
cadf87aa6b5fddb7a1437c3b572d2f89
INSERT
2024-07-24T05:55:41.553+00:00


2
David
2024-07-21
8a92a032edf462cfec7045f59d481172
UPDATE
2024-07-24T05:55:52.383+00:00



